# How to make pointer of react-leaflet popup point to the marker?

Tags: react-leaflet

How can I make the arrow on the pop-up box on a React-Leaftlet Popup point to the marker, instead of the bottom right of the box, as in the figure below?

[image]

Here is my code for the popup:

```
<Popup>
  <span>
    <p>Foo</p>
  </span>
</Popup>
```

I am using the `Popup.js` code from the `react-leaflet` repository examples folder. In that class, I don't see an option for setting an offset.

Even just removing that downward pointing arrow might be good enough.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can style the tip with `leaflet-popup-tip` css class. depending on your needs you can modify the position using css.

for example hiding the tip

```
.leaflet-popup-tip {
    display:none;
}
```